# x86 Qt app crashes on Mac OS 10.7 (Lion)

Tags: qt, crash, x86, osx-lion

Building a Qt app which targets Lion and Mountain Lion. The build server is on Mountain Lion. I have a 32bit dependency so I've compiled Qt 4.8.4 from source with `-arch x86`. The app runs fine on Mountain Lion but crashes on startup on Lion.

Here is the top of the stack trace:

```
1   QtGui    0x00c6a3e3 QMacPasteboardMime::~QMacPasteboardMime() + 2443
2   QtGui    0x00b904e4 QApplicationPrivate::initializeWidgetPaletteHash() + 6394
3   QtGui    0x00b91420 QApplicationPrivate::initializeWidgetPaletteHash() + 10294
4   QtGui    0x00c051d0 QApplicationPrivate::construct() + 222
5   QtGui    0x00c06052 QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int) + 100
```

Removing the 32bit dependency and building with the pre-build Qt 4.8.4 distribution fixes the problem. Does anybody see a problem with this Qt build configuration?

```
./configure \
    -debug-and-release \
    -developer-build \
    -opensource \
    -platform macx-g++ \
    -nomake examples \
    -nomake demos \
    -arch x86
```

I've also tried the `macx-llvm` make spec with the same result. Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use homebrew or the official binaries ? Both work fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying to get homebrew to build Qt in 32bit mode. The Qt formula switches on `MacOS.prefer_64_bit?`, which just calls `/usr/sbin/sysctl -n hw.cpu64bit_capable`. I hacked the `prefer_64_bit?` method to just return `false`, which seemed to work as the `./configure` line did contain `-arch x86`. However, the produced framework files were still `x86_64`. If you've been able to get homebrew to build Qt in 32bit mode, how did you do it?

Comment: This should have probably been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same behavior when building Lion compatible 32 bit QT apps. I managed to solve this issue by configuring Qt to use the older SDKs for 10.7, essentially making the build backward compatible with Lion.

First, I got the MacOSX10.7.sdk as a part from an older Xcode version via Apple Developer Center. The latest Lion ones are embedded in the DMG for Xcode 4.3.3 (`xcode_4.3.3_for_lion.dmg`), just mount the DMG and copy them from `/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs` to your current Xcode or to a more generic `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk`

Then, I configure QT (4.8.6 in my case) with an additional sdk parameter to match the target location of the SDKs.

`-sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk`

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue when building the Qt library 4.8.6 for win32 platform. After long investigation, I have identified the solution into Qt bug 27219, "This crash can be solved by setting:
export DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1". See: "https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-27219?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel"

For implementation details, see: "http://0xced.blogspot.ro/2006/07/dealing-with-outdated-open-source-libs.html"
You have to update into the Info.plist file to force flat namespace by setting the DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE environment variable. This is achieved by adding the following key in your Info.plist file:

```
<key>LSEnvironment</key>
<dict>
<key>DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE</key>
<string>YES</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: My own suggestion for adding the "-sdk" option above used to be enough when building from OSX 10.8 for a OSX 10.7 target. When rebuilding from OSX 10.10 with a newer xcode 6 toolchain for the same OSX 10.7 target it failed again, and I rediscovered this post. When combined with your answer the problem was solved.